# present perfect simple or continuous

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I can`t sleep because I have been watching a scary movie (shortly before, I am not watching it anymore). Does this sentence sound okay? Or do I have to use present perfect simple?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that works but it sounds a little unnatural to me - In this case I would probably say "I can't sleep because I (just) watched a scary movie."

But I would also say "I can't sleep because I have been drinking coffee."